# Discriminator Column Type

Tags: entity-framework

I've been looking at various Code First examples of TPT (Table Per Type) in Entity Framework.

I have an abstract base class with 4 concrete implementations, all of which share the exact same interface.  These are being stored using EF in a single table named after the abstract base class.

What I wish to do is use the EF Discriminator column, but without using the automatic table creation in Code First, instead adding the configuration and mappings manually.  Does anyone know if this would be possible and if so, what the type of the Discriminator column is (name, type, length, nullable, etc.) so I can create one manually?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sounds like TPH not TPT: [`Inheritance with EF Code First`](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

Comment: Fair point, do you know what the Discriminator column looks like if you wished to create it manually?

Comment: Here's a blog about TPH in database first: [`http://www.robbagby.com/`](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look through that.